# How can I correctly setup custom headers with nginx ingress?

Tags: kubernetes, nginx-ingress

I have the following configuration:

daemonset:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: DaemonSet
metadata:
  name: nginx-ingress
  namespace: nginx-ingress
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx-ingress
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx-ingress
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: nginx-ingress
      containers:
      - image: nginx/nginx-ingress:1.4.2-alpine
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        name: nginx-ingress
        ports:
        - name: http
          containerPort: 80
          hostPort: 80
        - name: https
          containerPort: 443
          hostPort: 443
        env:
        - name: POD_NAMESPACE
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: metadata.namespace
        - name: POD_NAME
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: metadata.name
        args:
          - -nginx-configmaps=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/nginx-config
          - -default-server-tls-secret=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/default-server-secret
```

main config:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: nginx-config
  namespace: nginx-ingress
data:
  proxy-set-headers: "nginx-ingress/custom-headers"
  proxy-connect-timeout: "11s"
  proxy-read-timeout: "12s"
  client-max-body-size: "5m"
  gzip-level: "7"
  use-gzip: "true"
  use-geoip2: "true"
```

custom headers:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: custom-headers
  namespace: nginx-ingress
data:
  X-Forwarded-Host-Test: "US"
  X-Using-Nginx-Controller: "true"
  X-Country-Name: "UK"
```

I am encountering the following situations:

- If I change one of "proxy-connect-timeout", "proxy-read-timeout" or "client-max-body-size", I can see the changes appearing in the generated configs in the controller pods
- If I change one of "gzip-level" (even tried "use-gzip") or "use-geoip2", I see no changes in the generated configs (eg: "gzip on;" is always commented out and there's no other mention of zip, the gzip level doesn't appear anywhere)
- The custom headers from "ingress-nginx/custom-headers" are not added at all (was planning to use them to pass values from geoip2)

Otherwise, all is well, the controller logs show that my only backend (an expressJs app that dumps headers) is server correctly, I get expected responses and so on.

I've copied as much as I could from the examples on github, making a minimum of changes but no results (including when looking at the examples for custom headers).

Any ideas or pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Please elaborate what you are originally trying to do :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Looks like you are using [kubernetes-ingress](https://github.com/nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress) from NGINX itself instead of [ingress-nginx](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx) which is the community nginx ingress controller.

If you see the [supported ConfigMap keys](https://github.com/nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress) for kubernetes-ingress none of the `gzip` options are supported. If you see the [ConfigMap options](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/master/docs/user-guide/nginx-configuration/configmap.md#use-gzip) for ingress-nginx you'll see all the gzip keys that can be configured.

Try switching to the [community](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/) nginx ingress controller.

Update:

You can also do it using the [configuration-snippet](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#configuration-snippet) annotation:

```yaml
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
   more_set_headers "X-Forwarded-Host-Test: US";
   more_set_headers "X-Using-Nginx-Controller: true";
   more_set_headers "X-Country-Name: UK";
   more_set_headers "Header: Value";
   ...
```

Comment: thanks! Had to dig a lot through docs but it did solve my problem!

Comment: Hello, is there anyway to read the value for the custom header through secret. I have a use case where I need to check static api token using custom header. Thank you

Comment: Hello, update: kubernetes nginx do accept gzip headers as in https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/configmap/#use-gzip

Comment: How about the traefik ingress instead of nginx ingress?

Comment: I get this error: `admission webhook "validate.nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io" denied the request: nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet annotation cannot be used. Snippet directives are disabled by the Ingress administrator`

Answer (score 42):

Use ingress rule annotations.

```
Example:
 apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: my-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
      more_set_headers "server: hide";
      more_set_headers "X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff";
      more_set_headers "X-Frame-Options: DENY";
      more_set_headers "X-Xss-Protection: 1";
  name: myingress
  namespace: default
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
```

I used nginx server 1.15.9

Comment: your example is for *response headers*, my question was about request headers for  backends.

Comment: @AndreiDascalu how did you manage to put those headers to requests rather than responses?

Comment: @Łukasz the main configuration of the ingress has a property: proxy-set-headers. The value for it is a namespace/configmap-name . where the target configmap is map of headers that will be set on requests going from the ingress to the backend service.

Comment: @AndreiDascalu You can use this for request header by changing to more_set_input_headers, see here https://github.com/openresty/headers-more-nginx-module#more_set_input_headers

Comment: configuration-snippet is disabled by default since 1.9.0 in the official k8s ngnix [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/main/docs/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations.md#configuration-snippet)

Answer (score 5):

For posterity:
nginx community controller => quay.io/kubernetes-ingress-controller/nginx-ingress-controller:0.21.0

nginx kubernetes controller => nginx/nginx-ingress:edge (as show in docs)

custom headers configmap for community => proxy-set-headers: "nginx-ingress/custom-headers"

custom headers configmap for kubernetes => add-headers: "nginx-ingress/custom-headers"

Answer (score 5):

```
annotations:
  nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
    more_set_input_headers "headername: value";
```

Answer (score 3):

When using Helm for **kubernetes/ingress-nginx** installation. Setup your custom header eg. *My-Custom-Header* as

```
controller:
  addHeaders:
    X-My-Custom-Header: Allow
```

This will add custom headers before sending response traffic to the client according to: https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/configmap/#add-headers
You can access it in logs:

```
controller:
   log-format-upstream: '{"x-my-custom-header" : "$http_x-my-custom-header"}'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new ConfigMap with your desired headers, and add them to each request response coming from your Nginx Ingress Controller that way :

```
kind: ConfigMap
apiVersion: v1
data:
  X-Content-Type-Options: "..."
  X-Frame-Options: "..."
metadata:
  name: custom-headers
  namespace: your-namespace
---
kind: ConfigMap
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: webauto-nginx-configuration
  namespace: your-namespace
data:
  add-headers: "your-namespace/custom-headers"
  ...
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: webauto-nginx-ingress-controller
  namespace: your-namespace
spec:
  replicas: 2
  ...
      containers:
        - name: nginx-ingress-controller
          image: k8s.gcr.io/ingress-nginx/controller:VERSION_YOU_WANT
          args:
            - /nginx-ingress-controller
            - --configmap=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/webauto-nginx-configuration
            ...
```