# Where do we add the x-frame-options header to the apis , when we have a ingress and kuberneters environment?

Tags: spring, nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I am looking for a exact yaml files. Where this can be added which can be picked automatically for every api and pages we deploy.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54083179/how-can-i-correctly-setup-custom-headers-with-nginx-ingress

Comment: Hi, @TrillionToBe, any progress?