# How to add content-security-policy to nginx ingress controller in eks

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, nginx-ingress

I have deployed an nginx ingress controller in my eks cluster. I want to add more security to my nginx deployment i.e add [content-security-policy](https://content-security-policy.com/examples/nginx/) header and the below

```
X-Frame-Options: 
Content-Security-Policy:
X-Content-Type-Options: 
X-XSS-Protection:
```

Is there any document i can follow to do it. please help.

I added in the configmap and turns out it didn't help as well.

Thanks

Comment: maybe duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54083179/how-can-i-correctly-setup-custom-headers-with-nginx-ingress

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can try this

```
ingress:
  enabled: true
  annotations:
     kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
     nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
        more_set_headers "X-Frame-Options: Deny";
        more_set_headers "X-Xss-Protection: 1; mode=block";
        more_set_headers "X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff";
        more_clear_headers "Cache-Control";
        more_set_headers "Cache-Control: must-revalidate";  
        proxy_set_header l5d-dst-override
```

Here is the list of all [nginx-configuration-annotations](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/main/docs/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations.md)

This fixes my issue and verifies it using [zaproxy](https://www.zaproxy.org/)